# Identify duplicate records in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have two tsv files as follows.

**tsv file number 1**

```
id    ingredients    recipe
code1  egg, butter   beat eggs. add butter
code2  tim tam, butter  beat tim tam. add butter
code3  coffee, sugar   add coffee and sugar and mix
code4  sugar, milk   beat sugar and milk together
```

**tsv file number 2**

```
id    ingredients    recipe
c009  apple, milk     add apples to milk
c110  coffee, sugar   add coffee and sugar and mix
c111  egg, butter   add egg, butter and sugar
c112  tim tam, sugar  beat tim tam. add butter
```

I want to remove the entries in the tsv files if,

1. they have shared ingredients (e.g. code3 and c110)
2. they have shared recipes (e.g., code2 and c112)

In the above example the output of the two tsv files should be as follows.

**tsv file number 1**

```
id    ingredients    recipe
code4  sugar, milk   beat sugar and milk together
```

**tsv file number 2**

```
id    ingredients    recipe
c009  apple, milk     add apples to milk
```

Can we do this using pandas? Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read your tsv files in use `pd.read_csv`:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(tsv_file_1, sep='\s\s+')
df2 = pd.read_csv(tsv_file_2, sep='\s\s+')

#Deal with spaces in columns names
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.strip()
df2.columns = df2.columns.str.strip()
```

Next use `isin` and the `~`(not operator):

```
df1_new = df1[~df1.ingredients.isin(df2.ingredients)]
df2_new = df2[~df2.ingredients.isin(df1.ingredients)]

print(df1_new)

      id  ingredients                        recipe
3  code4  sugar, milk  beat sugar and milk together

print(df2_new)

     id  ingredients              recipe
0  c009  apple, milk  add apples to milk
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. How to I perform the same for the recipes (2.they have shared recipes, but not shared ingredients (e.g., code2 and c112))?

Comment: In addition to ingredients or a separate condition?

Comment: it is not good to modified a question after asking it is far better to accept that solution then issue a new question.

Comment: I am sorry I did not add that second condition later. It was there before. I only edit the data so that it will be reflected :)

Comment: You still use the isn method on different columns.  df1.recipes.isin(df2.recipes) and you can combine this with an & or | with the ingredients condition and use boolean indexing again.